# Opening two ports at once in ssh

Tags: server, ssh

Using `ssh` server to enable remote access, new to Ubuntu as of last week.

I need ports 22 and 222 open, but can only get 22 open after installing the ssh server. I know thats the default port.

Anyone know how to open both ports? I'm pretty sure I have done all I can on the router side of things. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 12):

The `ssh` daemon from `openssh-server` can take multiple `Port` directive (in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) for assigning multiple ports to the single `ssh` daemon.

You need to indicate the port numbers after each `Port` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file e.g.:

```
Port 22
Port 222
```

Now restart the `ssh` daemon, for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
```